# create date-time by combining date and hour using dplyr and lubridate

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

My data has  a Flowday variable ( a date)  and an Interval variable  (double) that represents the hour of the day. I’m using `dplyr` and `lubridate` and trying to combine them to create a new datetime column with both the datend hour (first I need to subtract 1 from the hour because hour 24 isn’t recognized).

I've looked at lubridate examples and tried different syntax but haven't found one that works.

Here’s the data and code:

tiny_date

```
# A tibble: 7 x 3
  Element       Flowday    Interval
  <chr>         <date>        <dbl>
1 Sterlington 1 2019-03-21     1.00
2 Sterlington 1 2019-03-21     2.00
3 Sterlington 1 2019-03-21     3.00
4 Sterlington 1 2019-03-21     4.00
5 Sterlington 1 2019-03-21    22.0 
6 Sterlington 1 2019-03-21    23.0 
7 Sterlington 1 2019-03-21    24.0
```

`mutate(tiny_date, newdate = Flowday +hours(Interval - 1))`

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
>     Column `newdate` is of unsupported class POSIXlt

I expected to create a new date-time field that I can use to graph data. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If it's already in hours, why do you need to get `hours` again?

Comment: I need the date and hours combined in the same field so that I can graph on a timeline etc (and NelsonGon thanks for cleaning up the posting format).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but you could do:

```
     df %>% 
  mutate(newdate=as.POSIXct(hours((Interval-1))+ ymd(Flowday))) 


      Element    Flowday Interval             newdate
1 Sterlington 2019-03-21        1 2019-03-21 00:00:00
2 Sterlington 2019-03-21        2 2019-03-21 01:00:00
3 Sterlington 2019-03-21        3 2019-03-21 02:00:00
4 Sterlington 2019-03-21        4 2019-03-21 03:00:00
5 Sterlington 2019-03-21       22 2019-03-21 21:00:00
6 Sterlington 2019-03-21       23 2019-03-21 22:00:00
7 Sterlington 2019-03-21       24 2019-03-21 23:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `ymd_h`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
mutate(tiny_date, newdate = ymd_h(paste(Flowday, Interval - 1)))
```

Comment: However I don't think you should subtract 1 from Interval, as it represents the hour of the day.

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly. I subtract 1 because I want the 24 hours that make up the day of 2019-03-21. If I don't subtract 1, then 2019-03-21 hour 24 becomes 2019-03-22 hour 00, which leaves me with only 23 hours on March 21. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Here is base R way of doing it by pasting `Interval - 1` to `Flowday` and specifying the `format`.

```
as.POSIXct(paste(df$Flowday, df$Interval - 1), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H", tz = "GMT")

#[1] "2019-03-21 00:00:00 GMT" "2019-03-21 01:00:00 GMT" "2019-03-21 02:00:00 GMT"
#[4] "2019-03-21 03:00:00 GMT" "2019-03-21 21:00:00 GMT" "2019-03-21 22:00:00 GMT" 
#[7] "2019-03-21 23:00:00 GMT"
```