# In R how do you combine date and time character columns into a a single column?

Tags: r

I have two separate columns with date and time, respectively. I just want to combine them into a a single column. For example;

```
# Example data
Time<- as.character(c("11:15", "12:23", "15:42"))
Date<- as.character(c("2022-02-14", "2022-03-01", "2022-03,01"))                       
df<-data.frame(Time, Date)
class(df$Date)
class(df$Time)
```

The question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56511865/create-date-time-by-combining-date-and-hour-using-dplyr-and-lubridate) is similar but I don't have a double with "24" I need to deal with. I tried the following to no avail;

```
df$DateTime<-as.POSIXlt(paste0(df$Date, " ", df$Time, tz = "HST"))
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Using `mutate()` would be fine too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [create date-time by combining date and hour using dplyr and lubridate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56511865/create-date-time-by-combining-date-and-hour-using-dplyr-and-lubridate)

Comment: your `tz = "HST"` is inside `paste0`

Comment: @ moodymudskipper good point! I changed it, but then my formatting was incorrect.

Comment: @Andrea M Thanks for finding that question. I looked at a tone before I asked my own, but none of the answers given was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
#I think you might have put a comma instead of a dash in you example data. Corrected by gsub:    
df$Date <- gsub(",", "-",df$Date)

#Create a new combined date and time column:
df$DateTime <- paste(df$Date,df$Time)

#Convert the new column into a POSIXlt class object:
df$DateTime <- as.POSIXlt(df$DateTime,  c("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"), tz = "HST")
```

Another approach using piping actions from the `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(Date = gsub(",","-",Date)) %>% 
  mutate(DateTime = paste(Date,Time)) %>% 
  mutate(DateTime = as.POSIXlt(DateTime,  c("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"), tz = "HST")) -> df
```

Comment: Yes, doing it in these two steps worked perfectly on my real data as well. Thank you! Yes the "," instead of the "-" was an error in the example code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `tidyverse` and since the date and time are in the correct format/order, we don't necessarily need to specify the format of `DateTime`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(Date = str_replace_all(Date, ",", "-"),
         DateTime = as.POSIXlt(paste(Date, Time, sep = " "), tz = "HST"))
```

Or we can also use `lubridate`:

```
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
  mutate(Date = str_replace_all(Date, ",", "-"),
         DateTime = ymd_hm(paste(Date, Time, sep = " "), tz = "HST"))
```

**Output**

```
   Time       Date            DateTime
1 11:15 2022-02-14 2022-02-14 11:15:00
2 12:23 2022-03-01 2022-03-01 12:23:00
3 15:42 2022-03-01 2022-03-01 15:42:00
```